# wpf binding and stringformat in hexa

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following list binded to a list of bytes:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Payload}" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=0x{0:x2}}" Margin="2,1,2,1" MinWidth="25" MinHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

That Payload is an ObservableCollection. I get the values and display them in hexa but i want this to be a two way mode. At first i get values like 0x00 but i would like to modify that value let's say in 0xff and put that back in the Payload collection like 255.
I think i need a converter but i would need some help in that direction.

Comment: Just an FYI, you can highlight the entire code block and press CTRL+K to move it back 4 spaces at a time.

Comment: You are going to need to use an `IValueConverter` and on the `ConvertBack` method, convert it back to a byte.

Comment: you can find many valueconvertor guides/walkthrough on google. no big deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters mentioned, you can use an `IValueConverter` for that. Try this:

```
public class ByteToHexadecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || targetType != typeof(string)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        byte byteValue = 0;
        if (!byte.TryParse(value.ToString(), out byteValue)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        return byteValue.ToString("x2");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || targetType != typeof(byte)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        string stringValue = value.ToString();
        byte returnValue = 0;
        try { returnValue = System.Convert.ToByte(stringValue, 16); }
        catch { return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

You might need to tweak it a bit for your exact requirements, but it's all easily understandable. You can find out more about `IValueConverter` from the [`IValueConverter` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.